# Why is there a word in front of the for loop here?

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python and I saw this code to check for an even number, specifically tasked to use one line of code when creating a list and sorting even numbers into it.

I'm used to seeing:

```
for item in list: # etc etc
```

But why is there another `num`, in front of the for loop here:

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
even_numbers = [num for num in a if num % 2 is 0] # on this line
print(even_numbers)
```

Comment: What? The second thing is a list comprehension, not a for-loop.

Comment: It's called list comprehension, and the syntax is slightly different than a normal `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[num for num in a if num % 2 is 0]
```

In Python this is known as a "list comprehension." Its a short hand way of implementing the following code:

```
even_numbers = []
for num in a:
    if num % 2 == 0:
        even_numbers.append(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't actually a for loop, it's a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). That `num` in front of the `for` is the expression that gets used for each element in the new list.

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code,

```
even_numbers = [num for num in a if num % 2 is 0]
```

is equivalent to:

```
even_numbers = []
for num in a:
    if num % 2 == 0:
        even_numbers.append(num)
```

So, this part - `even_numbers.append(num)`, is equivalent to:

```
even_numbers = [num for ...]
```

So, the numbers `num` which are in list `a` and also divisible by 2 are added to the list `even_numbers`.

Answer (score 0):

In your simple case, it's a little hard to see why you would want the extra `num` in there.  So let's imagine something slightly more interesting, that you have a list of numbers, positive and negative, and what you want to iterate over the is *absolute value* of the numbers in the list.

In that case, you could write:

```
 absolutes = [abs(num) for num in a if num % 2 = 0]
```

That's also a pretty simple case, more typical might be:

```
 names = [company.name for company in companies if company.state = search_state]
```

In other words, the items produced by the list comprehension do not need to be the same items, or type of items, found in the original list.

Here's another less obvious example.  It produces a string of comma-separated question marks that you could use in building a parameterized SQL query using the IN operator:

```
 qmarks = ','.join(['?' for param in param_list])
```

In this case, the item returned from the list comprehension isn't even derived from the item in the original list.

Answer (score 0):

In a for loop you would say:

```
mylist = []
for num in a:
    if num % 2 is 0:
        mylist.append(num)
```

With the syntax you are seeing the num at the front is synonymous with the 4th line of code.

This syntax is actually a python list comprehension, but it does do something similar to the above for loop.

What is nice about this syntax is it lets you quickly/dynamically create/modify lists in a single line.

Another example that might help you understand why num is at the front is a simple line that converts a list of floats into a list of ints. Notice that in this example there is no if statement at the end and I have wrapped the output float in a int() cast.

```
floats_list = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5]
ints_list = [ int(float) for float in floats_list ]
```